# Retrieve list of (discovered) fields using Cloudwatch Logs SDK

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

On the documentation page for [Supported logs and Discovered fields](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_AnalyzeLogData-discoverable-fields.html), we can see an overview of what fields Cloudwatch might discover. How can I detect what fields my logstream contains using the SDK?

I know such functionality must exists, as you can see a nice little list of your discovered fields when using the Insights dashboard on the AWS Cloudwatch UI:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting my question, I looked at the documentation one more time and found the method that I needed: [getLogGroupFields](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchLogs.html#getLogGroupFields-property).